# Finding the length of an array using this function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

Can anyone explain to me how to call the following function to find the length of an array? Thanks!

```
int len(char* s)
{
    int k = 0;
    while (*s)
    {
        k++;
        s++;
    }
    return k;
}
```

Comment: How to call that function? Write `len(s)` where `s` is a pointer to a char array.

Comment: This function can't tell you the length of an array. It looks like a (bad) substitute for `strlen()` though, which gives you the length of a C-style string. Using C-style strings is the first thing to get rid of when learning C++  though...

Answer (score 1):

> *"can anyone explain me how to call this function to find the length of an array?"*

You can call it like this

```
char* array = "Hello World!";
int length = len(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

This function will not help you find the length of just any array - only some very specific ones:

- It needs to be an array of `char`,
- It needs to have non-zero values in all its elements except the last one
- The last element of the array must be zero.

In C arrays like that are created when you do this:

```
char array[] = "12345";
```

This is a six-element character array, with five initial elements occupied by non-zero character codes, and the sixth element occupied by zero.

Now the algorithm becomes clear: count elements until you hit zero, include zero in the count, and return the result:

```
char array[] = "12345";
int res = len(array);
```